# add elements to top RealmRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

I developing news feed like twitter, facebook and etc.

I have a server that gives me portions of articles for 10 pieces.

When I scroll down, new articles are loaded, added to the database and displayed in `RealmRecyclerView`.

I added `SwipeRefreshLayout` to update the data (in the case when new quotes came in).

I have a problem with adding new items to the top when i use `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

My idea was to sort new articles on id. In that case, when I scroll down the items with the smaller ones the id will be at the bottom, and when I use `SwipeRefreshLayout` new articles with higher id are download and adding in top list.

**MyFragment**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_all_quotes, container, false);
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    Realm.init(getActivity());
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new QuoteAdapter(realm.where(QuoteObject.class).findAllSortedAsync("id", Sort.DESCENDING), getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}


  @Override
public void onRefresh() {
    int position = realm.where(QuoteObject.class).findAll().size();
    DownloadDataFromServer.DownloadQuotes downloadQuotes =
            new DownloadDataFromServer.DownloadQuotes();
    try {
        DownloadDataFromServer.DownloadQuotes.FlagQuotes = true;
        downloadQuotes.execute(position+1).get();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "Error", e);
    }finally {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}
```

**RealmRecyclerViewAdapter**

```
class QuoteAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<QuoteObject, QuoteAdapter.AllQuotesViewHolder> {

 QuoteAdapter(OrderedRealmCollection<QuoteObject> quotes, Context context) {
    super(quotes, true);
    this.context = context;
    if (quotes.size() == 0) downloadData(0);
}

.
.
.
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final QuoteAdapter.AllQuotesViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    if (position == getData().size() - 1) downloadData(position);
....
}
```

**But it does not work, the new data is loaded but does not add to top**

Since I'm doing this for the first time, maybe I did not choose the right approach.
If you did this, tell how to create a news feed correctly.

Comment: don't they have a timestamp like "updated" date field or something? Personally I just did `findAllSortedAsync("updated", Sort.DESCENDING)` and it worked

Comment: can you show how you are updating the new data to adapter again? May be you need to use notifyItemRangeChanged or notifyItemMoved methods correctly.

Comment: @susheeltickoo `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` handles all notifyItem* calls automatically based on `OrderedRealmCollectionChangeSet`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Quotes do not have a date field.
I added your code, but it did not change anything.
The quotation is loaded, but not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a `updated` field by which you can do

```
findAllSortedAsync("updated", Sort.DESCENDING)
```

Then you might want to consider adding a `RANK` field, and sort based on that.

For example,

```
// when downloading new items by "SwipeToRefresh" from top
        // inside Realm transaction
                RealmResults<FeedItem> feedItems = dao.findAll(realm);
                for(int i = feedItems.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    FeedItem feedItem = feedItems.get(i);
                    feedItem.setRank(feedItem.getRank() + response.size());
                }
                long rank = 1;
                FeedItem defaultInstance = new FeedItem();
                for(FeedItemDTO dto : response) {
                    FeedItem realmObject = mapper.toRealmObject(realm, dto, defaultInstance);
                    realmObject.setRank(rank++);
                    dao.insertOrUpdate(realm, realmObject);
                }
```

And

```
// when download new items by scrolling to bottom
        // inside Realm transaction
                long count = dao.count(realm);
                long rank = count + 1;
                FeedItem defaultInstance = new FeedItem();
                for(FeedItemDTO dto : response) {
                    FeedItem realmObject = mapper.toRealmObject(realm, dto, defaultInstance);
                    realmObject.setRank(rank++);
                    dao.insertOrUpdate(realm, realmObject);
                }
```

---

```
public FeedItem toRealmObject(Realm realm, FeedItemDTO dto, FeedItemInterface defaultInstance) {
    if(defaultInstance == null) {
        defaultInstance = new FeedItem();
    }
    defaultInstance.setId(dto.getId());
    RealmList<FeedCategory> categoryIds = new RealmList<FeedCategory>();
    if(dto.getCategoryIds() != null) {
        for(Long categoryId : dto.getCategoryIds()) {
            FeedCategory feedCategory = feedCategoryRepository.findOne(realm, categoryId);
            if(feedCategory != null) {
                categoryIds.add(feedCategory);
            }
        }
    }
    defaultInstance.setCategoryIds(categoryIds);
    defaultInstance.setCreatedTime(new Date(dto.getCreatedTime()));
    defaultInstance.setUpdatedTime(new Date(dto.getUpdatedTime()));
    defaultInstance.setTitle(dto.getTitle());
    defaultInstance.setShortDescription(dto.getShortDescription());
    defaultInstance.setNumberOfLikes(dto.getNumberOfLikes());
    defaultInstance.setIsLiked(dto.getIsLiked());
    defaultInstance.setIsFavorited(dto.getIsFavorited());
    defaultInstance.setIsImportant(dto.getIsImportant());
    defaultInstance.setImageUrl(dto.getImageUrl());
    defaultInstance.setTypeCode(dto.getTypeCode());
    defaultInstance.setResultTypeCode(dto.getResultTypeCode());
    return defaultInstance;
}
```

Comment: What is dao? And how much I understood, in this code you change the order of the elements inside Realm itself? Why can not I change the order of the elements on id?

Comment: If you download the data and insert it into the Realm, then it will automatically update the adapter because the RealmResults is given to a RealmRecyclerViewAdapter (which adds the right `OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener` that handles this). So if your new items don't show up sorted by ID, then it means your IDs are not sorted to be in the order that you would like them to. ---- I change the order in Realm, because it also updates the sorted results.

Comment: Could you give an example of implementation mapper, please.

Comment: Here's a mapper

Comment: I do not understand why I need a mapper, and how db understands that it is necessary to sort by rank.
Maybe I did not explain what I want, or you did not understand me. If you have the time, look at my code in the githab please [link](https://github.com/Palantir-NR/Thinker2/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/palantir/thinker2)

Comment: Well you're definitely missing your @PrimaryKey annotation on your RealmObjects

Comment: Technically I always have a mapper between DTO (json object) and RealmObject because it's uncommon that your schema matches the moment you have primitive lists or relations.

Comment: Btw I copied that code from a real project where I had to implement a feed, so I can guarantee that it worked.